# PHP Validate $_GET['id'] for numbers only

Tags: php

i check validate numeric `$_GET['id']` using this code:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0 ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;

if($id){

echo "True";}

else{

echo "false";

}
```

Output:

```
  ID           RESULT
  1        =>  TRUE
  "        =>  FALSE
  <SCRIPT> =>  FALSE
  1.5      =>  TRUE
```

if id = 1.5 result TRUE!!

How do prevent this and safe id for Only valid number?!

Comment: `filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)`

Comment: You can use `is_int` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter_var` function:

```
var_dump(filter_var(1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));      // int(1)
var_dump(filter_var('1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));    // int(1)
var_dump(filter_var(1.5, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));    // bool(false)
var_dump(filter_var('1.5', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));  // bool(false)
var_dump(filter_var('<script></script>', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)); // bool(false)
```

If you want only numbers gt then 0, use `options` argument:

```
$options = array('options' => array('min_range' => 1));
var_dump(filter_var(-100, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options));   // bool(false)
var_dump(filter_var(0, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options));      // bool(false)
```

Comment: Sure this worked. if this was a function not better?

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using ctype_digit (works only with strings, it's ok with $_GET).

```
<?php
 $id = $_GET['id'];
if (ctype_digit($id)) {
  echo 'ok';
} else {
  echo 'nok';
}
?>
```

or you can try this:

```
$expr = '/^[1-9][0-9]*$/';
if (preg_match($expr, $id) && filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
 echo 'ok';
} else {
echo 'nok';
}
```